# Foreach loop is not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, scripting

I'm looking for some help with a foreach loop in Powershell. So the goal is to make new files in PowerShell depending on how many the user requests, so if the user requests to make 4 of the same files it should make four files in the requested folder. I just can't seem to figure out why my foreach loop is not making multiple files. It just makes one file each time. I've attached part of the code.

```
$FileName = Read-Host "Enter a file name"
$FilePath = Read-Host "Enter a file path"
$FileNumber = Read-Host "How many files need to be created?"
$num = 1

if ($FileName -gt 0) { 

    foreach($num in 4) {
    New-Item -Path $FilePath -Name $filepath
    #Write-Host $number $FileNumber
    }

}
```

Comment: [1] you are comparing `$FileName` to a `0` in your `if` test. that comparison is unlikely to work as you seem to expect. [*grin*] ///// [2] your `New-Item` call uses `$FilePath` for both the location AND the file name. ///// [3] how do you intend to handle fine name collisions? you have only provided ONE name ... but you seem to have had coded instructions to make _four_ files. ///// [4] your `foreach` is ... not likely to work at all. what on earth does `$Num in 4` mean? [*grin*] ///// [5] you ask for the number of files to make, but you never use that value.

Comment: I accidentally put `foreach($num in 4) {` while I was trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: ha! i have - of course - never made any "miztaak" of any kind. [*grin*] glad to see that you have two neat solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$FileName is string so although If( $FileName -gt 0) will return true, it's not a great practice.

Also there is nothing "in" the number 4.  The right side of In should be a collection of objects, which has not been created anywhere prior in the script.  Then you have a typo where you specify $FileName for both the name and path parameters.  At any rate, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$FileName = Read-Host "Enter a file name"
$FilePath = Read-Host "Enter a file path"
$FileNumber = Read-Host "How many files need to be created?"
$num = 1

if ($FileName) { 
$num..$FileNumber |
    ForEach-Object{
        $NewFile = $FileName + "_" + $_
        New-Item -Path $FilePath -Name $NewFile -ItemType File
    }
}
```

The if logic will work for your purposes. Then I'm sending a range of numbers down the pipeline for the ForEach-Object cmdlet.  Note: That's different than the ForEach keyword you were using.  At any rate concatenate the number, in this case $_ with the base file name that was previously entered then go ahead and create the item.

Hope that helps, let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on what Lee_Dailey said, I edited your code.  See my notes in the comments inline with the code.

```
$FileName = Read-Host "Enter a file name"
$FilePath = Read-Host "Enter a file path"
$FileNumber = Read-Host "How many files need to be created?"
# this next line shouldn't be needed here so I commented it out
# $num = 1

# You don't need "-gt 0".  Just use "if ($FileName)". which basically means:
# "if there is a value for $Filename then execute the block"
if ($FileName) {         
    # "foreach" really isn't the right approach here
    # use a for loop instead.  This one means:
    # start counting at $i (which is 1), if $i is less than or
    # equal to $FileNumber then execute the code block
    # and then increment $i at the end, making $i = 2
    # on the second trip through the loop
    for ($i=1; $i -le $FileNumber; $i++){
        # if you are making multiple files you can't give them all the
        # same name.  So you need to add a number at the end of each file
        # you create.  In this case $i
        $thisFileName = "$FileName" + "$i"
        New-Item -Path $FilePath -Name $thisFileName
        #Write-Host $number $FileNumber
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this greatly helps me out with an awesome explanation. I actually used the if statement because I wanted to create an error output. Thanks again to you and Lee_Dailey.